# Apply If condition in solr fieldlist

Tags: solr, lucene

I need a variable value, which will compute the value on the basis of condition I have used.

I need to apply if condition and in case that condition exists I need to return the value as 1 else 0

My logic is:

```
{!field f=temp_close_timing v='[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679 TO 2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679]'}
```

If we get the value from the above statement, we need to return true else return false.

I am not sure how to do this. I have tried exists condition here but I am not sure how to right the same in FL
eg:

```
fl=if((exists({!field f=temp_close_timing v='[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679 TO 2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679]'}),1,0),1,0)
```

but here I am getting error as `"Error parsing fieldname: Expected identifier at pos 3 str="`

I am not sure how to assign variable and if I assign variable that should be indexed separately.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to wrap it inside the localparam - could  `if(exists(query(temp_close_timing:[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679 TO 2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679])), 1, 0)` work?

Comment: I am getting error with this- ""Error parsing fieldname: Nested function query must use $param or {!v=value} forms. got 'if(exists(query(temp_close_timing:[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679 TO 2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679])), 1, 0)'"  ...query is defType=edismax&%20sow=true&%20fl=if(exists(query(temp_close_timing:[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679%20TO%202022-03-11T11:14:39.667679])),%201,%200)

Comment: It's telling you that you need to use an extra parameter to make parsing the query work properly. Something like: `&fl=if(exists(query($innerquery)), 1, 0)&innerquery=temp_close_timing:[2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679 TO 2022-03-11T11:14:39.667679]`